# How to detect MouseEnter and MouseLeave on TPanel-like in Lazarus

Tags: lazarus, mouseenter, mouseleave

I need a way, for Lazarus component (TPanel like), to detect when my component has mouse enter, and mouse leave. Delphi has messages `CM_MOUSEENTER` for that and I need same for Lazarus.

How can I get the same in Lazarus working for Win/Linux?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`TControl`](http://lazarus-ccr.sourceforge.net/docs/lcl/controls/tcontrol.html) class in Lazarus uses the same [`CM_MOUSEENTER`](http://lazarus-ccr.sourceforge.net/docs/lcl/lmessages/cm_mouseenter.html) message mechanism as in Delphi. Those messages don't use the OS' messaging system, but they are *injected* into the control message handler by the [`Perform`](http://lazarus-ccr.sourceforge.net/docs/lcl/controls/tcontrol.perform.html) method, so they are actually plaftorm independent.

However, for component developers and consumers there are dedicated methods, [`MouseEnter`](http://lazarus-ccr.sourceforge.net/docs/lcl/controls/tcontrol.mouseenter.html) and [`MouseLeave`](http://lazarus-ccr.sourceforge.net/docs/lcl/controls/tcontrol.mouseleave.html), whose in default implementation invoke [`OnMouseEnter`](http://lazarus-ccr.sourceforge.net/docs/lcl/controls/tcontrol.onmouseenter.html) and [`OnMouseLeave`](http://lazarus-ccr.sourceforge.net/docs/lcl/controls/tcontrol.onmouseleave.html) events.

How to consume this notification now depends on the situation in which you are. If you are writing your own [`TCustomPanel`](http://lazarus-ccr.sourceforge.net/docs/lcl/extctrls/tcustompanel.html) descendant component, you should override the mentioned methods like:

```
type
  TMyPanel = class(TCustomPanel)
  protected
    procedure MouseEnter; override;
    procedure MouseLeave; override;
  end;

implementation

procedure TMyPanel.MouseEnter;
begin
  inherited;
  // do your stuff here
end;

procedure TMyPanel.MouseLeave;
begin
  inherited;
  // do your stuff here
end;
```

If you are just a consumer of [`TControl`](http://lazarus-ccr.sourceforge.net/docs/lcl/controls/tcontrol.html) based component which doesn't publish the [`OnMouseEnter`](http://lazarus-ccr.sourceforge.net/docs/lcl/controls/tcontrol.onmouseenter.html) and [`OnMouseLeave`](http://lazarus-ccr.sourceforge.net/docs/lcl/controls/tcontrol.onmouseleave.html) events, then you can use e.g. intercept class to publish those events, or use the above code in the interceptor class, but to suggest you a proper way for this situation requires to know more about the control, since it may e.g. internally break the described mechanism for some reason.